# D-modules generated by derivatives of Delta function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, perverse-sheaves

We consider D-modules over the affine line $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$, i.e. modules of Weyl algebra $A_1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}[x,\partial]$. There is a set of microfunctions (ref. *A Primer of Algebraic D-modules*, S.C.Coutinho), denoted by $\mathcal{M}$, which is an $A_1(\mathbb{C})$-module. Let $\delta\in \mathcal{M}$ be the Delta microfunction, and the D-module generated by it can be identified to $\mathbb{C}[\partial]$.

Consider $\delta^{(m)}=\partial^{m} \delta$, and let
$$
A_1(\mathbb{C}) \cdot \delta^{(m)}
$$
be the D-modules generated by $\delta^{(m)}\in \mathcal{M}$. It's not hard to varify that
$$
A_1(\mathbb{C})\cdot \delta^{(m)}\simeq A_1(\mathbb{C})/(x^{m},x\partial +m).
$$

I have two questions about those D-modules.

1. I find that $x\cdot \delta^{(m)}=x\partial^{m}\delta=(\partial^{m}x-m\partial^{m-1})\delta=-m \delta^{(m-1)}$ as $x\cdot \delta=0$. Therefore, I think there are isomorphisms
   $$
   A_1(\mathbb{C}) \cdot \delta=A_1(\mathbb{C}) \cdot \delta^{(m)}.
   $$
   But this seems unreasonable when considering the quotient modules.
2. I want to know which perverse sheaf corresponds with D-module generated by $\delta$. Consider the resolution
   $$
   A_1(\mathbb{C}) \xrightarrow{\cdot x} A_1(\mathbb{C}).
   $$
   After derived tensoring the canonical sheaf, this complex becomes (after taking cohomology sheaf)
   $$
   0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}.
   $$
   Do I get the correct result? (**Edit:** This is wrong. It should be skyscraper sheaf as Sawin said in comment.)

Comment: The $A_1(\mathbb C)$-module generated by $\delta$ is simple. So it is generated by any of its non-zero elements, in particular, $\delta^{(m)}$.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop That's right. This module has multiplicty 1.

Comment: I think you're supposed to get the complex $\mathcal O_{\mathbb A^1} \to_{\cdot x} \mathcal O_{\mathbb A^1}$, which is quasi-isomorphic to the skyscraper sheaf $\mathbb C$ at $0$. (Is that what your $\mathbb C$ was meant to denote)?

Comment: @WillSawin Actually, I made a mistake here. Now I know that it is quasi-isomorphic to skyscraper sheaf, because the cokernel is the same as the cokernel of $\mathcal{O}(-1\cdot 0)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @WillSwain, so your quasi-isomorphism lies at the basis to the answer to my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97361/explaining-mukai-fourier-transforms-physically, right?