# The Dedekind eta function in physics

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

This interesting little fellow (a nice introduction is the video "[Mock Modular Forms are Everywhere](https://video.ethz.ch/speakers/its/2019/spring/colloquium/9a64c3f5-be20-4b24-9966-59b16f082cb9.html)" by Cheng and Felder) popped up in some operator algebra (Witt / Virasoro Lie algebra) I was exploring, so I've been curious about where else the Dedekind $\eta$-function makes a cameo appearance and found that in physics it's related to the

1. statistical  parameters of solvable Ising models

(See "[The Reasonable and Unreasonable Effectiveness of Number Theory in Statistical Mechanics](http://books.google.co.jp/books?hl=en&lr=&id=j-pLi01XbFUC&oi=fnd&pg=PA21&dq=GE%20Andrews%20reasonable%2band%2bunreasonable%2beffectiveness%2bof%2bnumber%2btheory&ots=tUl15FN6zA&sig=n1cTHjUpWjY42TLrl-OQxkz2xaY#v=onepage&q=GE%20Andrews%20reasonable%2band%2bunreasonable%2beffectiveness%2bof%2bnumber%2btheory&f=false)" by G. Andrews and "[Introduction to Exactly Solvable models in Statistical Mechanics](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Etracy/selectedPapers/1980s/CV31.pdf)" by C. Tracy.)

The difference between the average local occupation densities of two sub-lattices of a hard hexagon model of a lattice gas given on pp. 368-371 of Tracy is $R(\tau)=\frac{n(\tau)\eta(5\tau)}{\eta^2(3\tau)}$.

2. partition functions (statistical mechanics variety) for colored bosons moving on a
   line  (1/24 is the associated Casimir energy) and one-color fermions
3. operator traces (characters) for the infinite dimensional Lie algebras $\widehat{su}_n$,
   equivalent to 2-Dim current algebras
4. partition function of a microscopic black-hole in a 5-Dim D-brane
5. string theory guage corrections

(For 2-5, see "[Nucleon Structure, Duality and Elliptic Theta Functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9912502)" by W. Scott. For item 2, see also "[Vertex Operators and Modular Forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4460)" by G. Mason and M. Tuite.)

From pg. 39 of "[Fivebrane instantons](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5792) ..." and on pg. 11 of "[D3 instantons](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1109) ...,"
a correction to the field basis (of the RR axion dual to D3-branes) in type IIB string perturbation theory related to the action of S-duality in ten dimensions:

$\tilde{c_a} \mapsto \tilde{c_a}-\tilde{c}_{2,a}\:\epsilon(g)$ where, with $g=\binom{a\:\:b}{c\:\:d}$,

$$\exp(2\pi i \epsilon(g))=\frac{\eta\left [ \frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d} \right ]}{\left ( c\tau+d \right )^{\frac{1}{2}}\eta(\tau)}.$$

6. partition function in 2+1 dimensions and vanishing chemical potential of
   non-relativistic fermions in a constant magnetic field

("[Nonrelativistic Fermions in Magnetic Fields: a Quantum Field Theory Approach](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108022)" by O. Espinosa, J. Gamboa, S. Lepe, and F. Mendez)

7. physics of gauge theories and the Dirac operator

(See "[The Logarithm of the Dedekind $\eta$ Function](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/atiyahlg.pdf)" by M. Atiyah.)

Michael Atiyah even goes so far as to say, "It seems therefore timely to attempt to survey the whole development of the theory of $\log(\eta)$, putting results in their natural order and in the appropriate general context. This is the aim of the present paper, in which the emphasis will be strongly geometrical. In a sense we shall show that the latest ideas from physics [circa 1987] provide the key to a proper understanding of Dedekind's original results."

[ 7.5 Edit 1/18/21: The lecture "[A geometric approach to the modular flow on the space of lattices](http://math.sun.ac.za/bbartlett/assets/Dedekind_eta.pdf)" by Bruce Bartlett interleaves topics presented by Atiyah above and Ghys below.]

8. knots and dynamics

(See "[Knots and Dynamics](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_I/15.pdf)" by E. Ghys, and Chapter 2 A New Twist in Knot Theory in Dana MacKenzie's book [What's Happening in the Mathematical Sciences Vol. 7](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=yBL54nHAwXsC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=The%20Logarithm%20of%20the%20Dedekind%20eta%20%20Function%20%20Atiyah&source=bl&ots=NsCYEW6gaQ&sig=7Tc3R-nSY4USVutxuCy1pf9zeQ4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jfa7UMOSCabNmgW43ICYBg&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=The%20Logarithm%20of%20the%20Dedekind%20eta%20%20Function%20%20Atiyah&f=false).)

Ghys presents the equation  $$24\log\eta\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right)=24\: \log(\eta(\tau))+6\: \log(-(c\tau+d)^{2})+2\pi i\:\mathfrak{R}\left(\binom{a\: b}{c\: d}\right)
 $$

where $\mathfrak{R}$ is the Rademacher function, which he relates to the linking number

between two knots related to modular/Lorenz flow: “For every hyperbolic element $A=\binom{a\: b}{c\: d}$ in $PSL(2,Z)$, the linking number between the [modular/Lorenz] knot $k_A$ and the trefoil knot $l$ is equal to $\mathfrak{R}(A)$ ....”

9. string/brane partition functions, propagators, and metrics

In "[String Theory](http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Es.halter/st1/)" by S. Nibbelink, $\eta$ occurs in the denominator of string partition functions for fermionic and bosonic zero modes (pp. 163-7).

A coefficient in the 10-dim metric for a 7-brane is given as $e^{\phi}=\tau_2 \eta^2\bar{\eta}^2|\prod_{i=1}^{k}(z-z_i)^{-\frac{1}{12}}|^2$ on pg. 493 of "[Supergravity vacua and solitons](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0918)" by G. Gibbons.

**In what other contexts in physics does the Dedekind $\eta$ function take a bow?**

(Edit) Moreover, since this is a community wiki and not a test question with one best answer but an attempt to come to a better understanding of the $\eta$-function and associated math and physics, I invite people to expand on any of the items with specifics (e.g., exact formulas), more references, and/or insightful commentaries (e.g., what you believe are important aspects of the references).

Other appearances: In Gliozzi's "The Infrared Limit of QCD Effective String" on pg. 14; Panero's "A numerical study of confinement in compact QED" on pg. 4; Zahed's "Holographic Pomeron and Primordial Viscosity" on pg. 1; Caselle and Pinn's "On the Universality of Certain Non-Renormalizable Contributions in Two-Dimensional Quantum Field Theory" on pg. 3; Billo, Casselle, and Pellegrini's "New numerical results and novel effective string predictions for Wilson loops" on pg. 6 and 15; and Basar, Kharzeev, Yee, and Zahed's "Holographic Pomeron and the Schwinger Mechanism" on pg. 7.

Comment: Do you consider conformal field theory covered in your question? ...because this is not entirely unrelated to the Ising model.

Comment: Well, you'll find it discussed in Nash. Gannon also discusses a boson on a circle.

Comment: If your goal in asking this question goes beyond simply accumulating a list of interesting physics topics, I think it would be important to note how precisely $\eta$ appears, rather than simply pointing out that it is mentioned in a paper.  For example, in many statistical partition functions and Fock space characters, it appears in the denominator, since the reciprocal of $\eta$ is a generating function that counts partitions of integers.

Comment: Related: "On determinant line bundles" by Freed.

Comment: Related "K3 Surfaces, N=4 Dyons, and the Mathieu Group M24" by Miranda Cheng http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5415

Comment: See also the same question on PhysicsOverflow with additional answers: https://www.physicsoverflow.org/17263

Comment: See pg. 145 of "Signatures in algebra, topology and dynamics" by Ghys and Ranicki https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.09258

Comment: See also "Lorenz and modular flows: a visual introduction" by Ghys and Leys http://www.josleys.com/articles/ams_article/Lorenz3.htm

Comment: And "The Modular Flow on the Space of Lattices" at the n-Category Cafe https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/the_modular_flow_on_the_space.html

Comment: The characters of vertex algebras are often modular forms, for instance, the character of the Heisenberg/rank 1 free boson vertex algebra at a certain charge is $\eta(q)^{-1}$. Zhu proved a more precise result in ``Modular invariance of characters of vertex operator algebras''. This comment is probably just a mathematical rephrasing of some of the things already mentioned here already.

Comment: Also Ooguri, "Lecture 9: Riemann surfaces, elliptic functions"  https://ocw.u-tokyo.ac.jp/lecture_files/sci_03/9/notes/en/ooguri09.pdf

Comment: @S.Carnahan, isn't that rather obvious from the first examples in statistical physics which always relates statistical parameters such as the system's energy, entropy, temperature, etc. to averages over a distribution (relative count) of states? The papers devote rather large sections to the explanation of the exact connection of the Dedekind eta to a counting of the states involved. This is a question rather than a treatise.

Comment: Occurs in the denominator (under a theta function) of the determinant of a chiral Dirac operator in "Theta Functions, Modular Invariance, and Strings" by Alvarez-Gaume, Moore, and Vafa.

Comment: As Steve Huntsman noted, the Dedekind eta function occurs in Moonshine Beyond the Monster by Gannon.

Answer (score 8):

The Dedekind eta function shows up in three-dimensional quantum gravity: http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0155 (Alexander Maloney, Edward Witten, Quantum Gravity Partition Functions in Three Dimensions). On page 17 a basic partition function $Z_{0,1}$ of the theory is calculated as $$Z_{0,1}(\tau)=\frac{1}{|\eta(\tau)|^2}|\bar q q|^{-(k-1/24)}|1-q|^2.$$ It also appears in the calculation of supergravity partition functions in sec.7.

The Dedekind eta function also enters in (supersymmetric) physics through mock modular forms: http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4074 (Atish Dabholkar, Sameer Murthy, Don Zagier, Quantum Black Holes, Wall Crossing, and Mock Modular Forms).

A good review of mock modular forms is [http://mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/114.pdf](http://mathcs.emory.edu/%7Eono/publications-cv/pdfs/114.pdf) (Ken Ono, Unearthing the visions of a master: harmonic Maass forms and number theory).

I first heared about Dedekind Eta Function in the physics context via Freeman Dyson's lovely essay
["Missed opportunities"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-78/issue-5/Missed-opportunities/bams/1183533964.full).

Comment: that last link is broken:  http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183533964

Comment: The broken link has been now fixed.